# What is the configuration option "htmllibmanager.excluded.path.list.name" of the Adobe Granite HTML Library Manager used for?

Tags: aem

In AEM Adobe Granite HTMl Library manager there are a lot of configuration options.

I would like to know what `htmllibmanager.excluded.path.list.name` is being used for.

[image: Granite HTML Library Manager OSGi configuration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The htmllibrarymanager has a node listener that checks for client libs under certain path. This trigger is responsible for merging and compaction of clientlibs (if enabled) for the pages. The exclude path (like the name says) skips the listener's handling of these concatenation and compaction tasks. It is normally configured to exclude pre-compiled scripts in AEM and cloud products.

Comment: I add /etc/clientlibs in this configuration.But it is still loading the clientlibs under that.

Comment: /etc/clientlibs cannot be configured to be ignored. It's the default (and hard-coded) clientlibs path. Why do you want to ignore it?

Comment: Just for the testing purpose.Ok so you are saying,If i have a clientlibs under /apps/test,I can ignore  the loading of this clientlibs by adding it in this field.

Comment: It's not about loading. It's the compaction and minification trigger. Client libs are included regardless of their location's excluded path. This config is for the minification of CSS/JS files under the path.

Comment: I have created a clientlib under /apps/myproject,added it in this configuration,but still it is doing minification of js files.Can you please try and help me out.

Comment: In this case I think this is being overridden by the Allowed Libraries Path configuration where /apps is set by default. Although, if you remove this config, the clientlibs won't be included

Comment: i.net Thanks for the clarification.Actually I need to restart the instance after changing in this configuration. It appends the .min selector in the files,but it doesn't compress them.Thanks again.

Comment: Correct, any config changes to the htmllibrarymanager requires a restart of that package as the config is only parsed in the activation method.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML Library Manager uses a JCR Event Listener **purely** for the purpose of cache invalidation, i.e. when the file at `/apps/myco/clientlib/js/somefile.js`, it knows to invalidate the cached client library which contains this file (presumably `/apps/myco/clientlib`). The configuration `htmllibmanager.excluded.path.list.name` defines a set of paths under which events are not observed. It has nothing to do with minification or concatenation in the sense that if you were to create a client library under any of the excluded paths, it would still get concatenated and minified (depending on the configuration).

You should **not** change this value. It is listed on https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-3/develop/ref/javadoc/deprecated-configurations.html as to be changed only by Adobe. And if you do change it (which again, you shouldn't), you definitely shouldn't change it to include any paths which *may* contain client libraries as that would result in stale cache entries.