# disable concatenate on clientlibs AEM

Tags: aem

So I've been studying AEM (Adobe Experience Manger) for a new project. I've just found out how I can add assets such as stylesheets and javascripts. I've noticed that AEM concatenate the files into a singular file

[image]

```
<sly data-sly-use.clientlib="/libs/granite/sightly/templates/clientlib.html" />
<sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.css @categories='globe-onboarding'}" />
<sly data-sly-call="${clientlib.js @ categories='globe-onboarding'}" />
```

Is there way to have it broken down into several chunks of files instead of having it mash into a singular `clientlib.js` file like the example below

```
<sly data-sly-call="${libs.js @ categories='globe-onboarding'}" />
<sly data-sly-call="${apps.js @ categories='globe-onboarding'}" />
```

Comment: You can create as many clientilbs as needed, and include them in your templates. Check this: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/sites/developing/using/clientlibs.html

Answer (score 0):

Client libraries are just groupings of files that get combined into one, so you can create multiple client libraries and then just include the one you want when you want that chunk.  So in your case, if you want two chunks of output, you would create two different client libraries and include them both in your page.

Many times the simplest option is to request your URL with the `?debugClientLibs=true` querystring [for debugging](https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/experience-manager-65/developing/introduction/clientlibs.html#debugging-tools).  Then you can see all the individual files to debug, but still get the combined/minified version when you are not debugging.

You can also exclude paths from concatenation.  Check out [What is the configuration option "htmllibmanager.excluded.path.list.name" of the Adobe Granite HTML Library Manager used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44668024/what-is-the-configuration-option-htmllibmanager-excluded-path-list-name-of-the/44675458#44675458)